# Microsoft one drive to SQl Server using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, onedrive

can i use microsoft 1 drive to store the flat file and can i load the files from one drive to sql server database suing SSIS.Can any one share a thought on an alternative.Keeping the master data flat file on cloud and making it available on sql server.We do not want to download those files stored in cloud.The thing is would like to create ssis package to read the files on the cloud

Comment: Why cant you try once and check ?

Comment: I have not got access on any cloud.We are thinking about a strategy to get flat file data from one of the child companies.We do not want to download the flatfile data to our system.So,just wondering any body gone through similar situvation